# Prevent scroll pull beyond extent of the item on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, browser, scroll

This might have been answered but I am really struggling to describe this issue.

On my [website](https://atap.geolytix.net/map?seamless_locales) I have map div, a transparent slider div on top and non transparent info div below the transparent slider.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

The css allows the info div to be slid over the map.

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#map {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

#spacer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

.info {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px slategrey;
}
```

Here is a picture of the undesired effect.

[image]

It shouldn't be possible to pull the sliding div away from the bottom of the browser.

Is there a html & css solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking at here is a browser drawback, which can be overriden in safari under ios by using a non-standard webkit rule called `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` , you can find information about it **[here on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)** I have ran into this issue numerous times in the past, but I can't remember finding a fix for it.

You can try **[this simple "hack"](http://www.teamtownend.com/2013/07/ios-prevent-scrolling-on-body/)** to bypass it, but I don't think this is a good idea though:

```
body.lock-position {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

You can find more information about this issue **[here.](http://blog.christoffer.me/six-things-i-learnt-about-ios-safaris-rubber-band-scrolling/)**

Comment: I just tested this on a friends iDevice with chrome. Same behaviour. It must be an iOS issue and not just related to the Safari browser.

Comment: Well that is the default behavior for iOS no matter the browser.